# Autosave CKeditor content to Mysql using JQuery and PHP

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I spent 2 days reading and trying many solutions to autosave form content with CKeditor, but I couldn't solve the problem, maybe because I am not familiar with JQuery and JavaScript tricks.
My app depends on this tutorial: [AUTO SAVE A DRAFT WITH PHP AND JQUERY](http://www.rrpowered.com/2014/07/auto-save-a-draft-with-php-and-jquery/).
The value of CKeditor is always null. When I remove the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

everything works fine.

Please, when you suggest the solution, give me more details about how to implement it.

I am not sure, but I guess I need to workarround here:

```
$(function () {
$.post("php/rrpowered-autosave.php", function (data) {
    $("[name='title']").val(data.title);
    $("[name='body']").val(data.body);
}, "json");
setInterval(function () {
    $.post("php/rrpowered-autosave.php", $("form").serialize());
}, 2000);
});
```

Note: Say that the "body" is the place where the CKeditor content goes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this post is old... i stumbled upon this one while searching solution with the same problem 40 minutes ago. if you already found an answer to this, it will be appreciated if you would share it here..

i thought i should get back here and share what helped me:

(from http://www.davidado.com/2011/08/21/using-ckeditor-with-jquery/)

```
function CKupdate(){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
                $('textarea').trigger('keyup');
}
```

and using the autosave plugin from
http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Autosave-Form-Content-autoSave.html